# When should I use logInfo and when writeln?

Tags: logging, d, vibed

Vibed have logInfo class. In case when I need to write to console information about connection status what's better to use `writeln` or `logInfo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vibe, you should always use the vibe functions. Normal `writeln` locks the output which keeps it sequential and such... but that's a problem in the async environment of vibe.d because it will slow down the other threads trying to log too.

Comment: What about logger from Phobos? Does it's analog of vibed's logInfo?